# Why my php array return only recent/last post activities

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I create a jquery which sent data to a php file and after query(If any data found at sql) php return data to jquery by json_encode for append it.

Jquery sent two type data to php file:

**1st:** page id

**2nd:** post ids (a jquery array sent them to php file)

If I used `print_r($_REQUEST['CID']); exit;` on php file for test what he get from jquery, Its return and display all post ids well.

But if I make any reply on particular post, Its only return recent post reply.

That means, if I have 3 post like: *post-1st*, *post-2nd*, *post-3rd* ;  my php return only *post-3rd* activities.

I want my script update any post reply when it submitted at sql.

my wall.php

```
    // id is dynamic
<div class="case" data-post-id="111"></div> 
<div class="case" data-post-id="222"></div>
<div class="case" data-post-id="333"></div>

//Check for any update after 15 second interval by post id.
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var CID = [];
$('div[data-post-id]').each(function(i){
    CID[i] = $(this).data('post-id');
});

function addrep(type, msg){
CID.forEach(function(id){
    $("#newreply"+id).append("<div class='"+ type +""+ msg.id +"'><ul>"+ msg.detail +"</ul></div>");
});
}
var tutid = '<?php echo $tutid; ?>';
function waitForRep(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/server.php",
        cache: false,
        data: {
        tutid : tutid,
        CID : CID
    },
        timeout:15000, 
        success: function(data){ 
            addrep("postreply", data);
            setTimeout(
                waitForRep, 
                15000 
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            setTimeout(
                waitForRep, 
                15000); 
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForRep();
});
</script>
```

server.php (may be problem in my array or something else)

```
while (true) {
if($_REQUEST['tutid'] && $_REQUEST['CID']){
foreach($_REQUEST['CID'] as $key => $value){

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 second'));
$res = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM comments_reply WHERE post_id =".$value." AND qazi_id=".$_REQUEST['tutid']."  AND date >= '$datetime' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));

} // array close

$rows =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);  

        $row[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $rows);

        $data = array();

$data['id'] = $rows['id']; 
$data['qazi_id'] = $rows['qazi_id'];
//ect all

// do something and echo $data['detail'] = $detail;

    if (!empty($data)) {
        echo json_encode($data);
        flush();
        exit(0);
    }

}  // request close
sleep(5);
}  // while close
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare CID array like this:

```
var CID = new Array();
```

Comment: why will i do this. where is the problem you think?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looping through the CIDs and running an SQL query for each one, but you're only retrieving the results once, outside of the loop. You'll only get the last query's results if you run

```
$rows =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
```

outside of the CIDs foreach loop.

@koc:
Unfortunately, it won't be as simple as moving the closing loop bracket. If you're trying to retrieve multiple datasets in one AJAX call, then you'll need to handle multiple datasets in your AJAX's success callback, or in your addrep() function. Here's one way to do it, but you can do it many different ways depending on what you're ultimately trying to do:

```
while (true) {
  if($_REQUEST['tutid'] && $_REQUEST['CID']){
    $data = array();
    foreach($_REQUEST['CID'] as $key => $value){

      date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
      $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 second'));
      $res = mysqli_query($dbh,"
        SELECT *
        FROM comments_reply
        WHERE post_id =".$value."
          AND qazi_id=".$_REQUEST['tutid']."
          AND date >= '$datetime'
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
      ") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));

      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)
      $data[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
    } // array close

    //$rows =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);  
    //$row[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $rows);
    //$data = array();

    //$data['id'] = $rows['id']; 
    //$data['qazi_id'] = $rows['qazi_id'];
    //ect all

    // do something and echo $data['detail'] = $detail;

    if (!empty($data)) {
      echo json_encode($data);
      flush();
      exit(0);
    }

  }  // request close
  sleep(5);
}  // while close
```

then in your Javascript:

```
...
success: function(data){
  for (var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
    addrep("postreply", data[i]);
  }
  setTimeout(waitForRep, 15000);
},
...
```

But again, that's just an example. I don't really know what your datasets look like or how you want the data to be passed around and used. This is just an idea that hopefully gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: If I replace ` } // array close` before ` }  // request close` it's now working for 1st post. confused..!! Thank you. Have anything more please?